# Смена событий для div. JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть событие наложенное на `#set-view-bid` которое сворачивает и разворачивает форму. В первом случае оно нужно, а во втором допустим нужен просто переход при клике на другую страницу сайта, не разворачивая форму. Как это осуществить с помощью JQuery?

```
<?if(strpos($APPLICATION->GetCurDir(), '/bids/') === false ):?>
    if ($('#nameWork_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>').val()) {
        $('#set-view-bid').html('<b>Просмотреть заявку<b>');
    }
    <?endif;?>
```

В коде указан второй случай. В нем просто идет смена названия у `div`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить эту строку

```
$('#set-view-bid').html('<b>Просмотреть заявку<b>');
```

следующим кодом:

```
$('#set-view-bid').empty();
$('<b>Просмотреть заявку<b>')
    .appendTo($('#set-view-bid'))
    .click(function() {
        document.location.href = 'page_url';
});
```

Comment: Ваш код работает, но он не отменяет развертывания формы. Есть ли способы прям подмены одной функции на другую))?

Comment: покажите больше кода, в частности - там где выводится форма